# XAMPP has MySQL built-in, not MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, mariadb, installation

Everything says XAMPP has MariaDB now, but using the latest download link it only has MySQL. Am I missing something? For my needs I'd rather use MariaDB, but can make due with MySQL if need be, but it might create some minor headaches down the road. Is it simply because I'm on Windows?

Comment: Try `SELECT @@version;` in a client. Does it say something about MariaDB? MariaDB is based on MySQL, so many commands will be the same as MySQL, but querying the version will tell you for sure which is installed.

Comment: That said, this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. They want only questions about specific code problems on this site, not installation help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @BillKarwin my bad, thought this was the right place. Is there a more appropriate section for something like this? To me this makes sense as it would qualify under the "software tools commonly used by programmers" condition, no? When I do the SELECT @@version; I get an error, pretty sure this is just straight MySQL though.

Answer (score 0):

From the `MariaDB` Wiki:

> MariaDB is a community-developed, commercially supported fork of the
>   MySQL relational database management system (RDBMS), intended to
>   remain free and open-source software under the GNU General Public
>   License. Development is led by some of the original developers of
>   MySQL, who forked it due to concerns over its acquisition by Oracle
>   Corporation in 2009.[6]

`XAMPP` (currently version 7.4.3) ships with `MariaDB` (currently version 10.4.11)

The current version you're using should come up when logging via the `cmd line` or if you do a `SELECT VERSION();`

You can find a full list of differences between `MariaDB` and `MySQL` [here](https://www.guru99.com/mariadb-vs-mysql.html)